# How to remove 'Date' and 'Untitled' letters when print page appears in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the print page appearing when button is pressed.But i am getting unnecessary things in print page like:

[image]

How can i remove those fields?

My running code is (Snippet is not working you can directly copy and paster and run it):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv(divID) {
            //Get the HTML of div
            var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
            //Get the HTML of whole page
            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

            //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
            document.body.innerHTML = 
              "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
              divElements + "</body>";

            //Print Page
            window.print();

            //Restore orignal HTML
            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;


        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="printablediv" style="width: 100%; background-color: Blue; height: 200px">
        Print me I am in 1st Div
    </div>
    <div id="donotprintdiv" style="width: 100%; background-color: Gray; height: 200px">
        I am not going to print
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Print 1st Div" onclick="javascript:printDiv('printablediv')" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the header you need to set margin to zero.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page 
        {
            size:  auto;
            margin: 0mm;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add some css.

```
@page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mfLsa82q/